# Simple pagination with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pagination

I want to include a "pagination" with jquery or javascript to my website.

Therefore, I have created the following simple html-code:

```
<div class="post-list">

    <div class="post">
    <h3> head1 </h3>
    <p> Test1 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post">
    <h3> head2 </h3>
    <p> Test2 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post">
    <h3> head3 </h3>
    <p> Test3 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post">
    <h3> head4 </h3>
    <p> Test4 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post">
    <h3> head5 </h3>
    <p> Test5 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post">
    <h3> head6 </h3>
    <p> Test6 </p>
    </div>

</div>


    <div class="pagination">

    </div>
```

I am Newbie in web development and I don't know how to write a simple
javascript or jquery code to make a pagination work.
After searching the internet I haven't found any simple solution for it.

Therefore, I would really appreciate it if you could tell me a jquery or javascirpt code that I can apply to this html code.

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: just use https://jplist.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
<a href="#" id="prev">Prev page</a>
<a href="#" id="next">Next page</a>
<div class="pagination">
    <div class="post" id="page1"> <!-- I gave every "page" an ID. -->
        <h3> head1 </h3>
        <p> Test1 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="page2">
        <h3> head2 </h3>
        <p> Test2 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="page3">
        <h3> head3 </h3>
        <p> Test3 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="page4">
        <h3> head4 </h3>
        <p> Test4 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="page5">
        <h3> head5 </h3>
        <p> Test5 </p>
    </div>

    <div class="post" id="page6">
        <h3> head6 </h3>
        <p> Test6 </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

All you need to do in this situation is dynamically hide every page except the one you want to see:

```
function showPage(page) {
    $('.pagination .post:not(#page'+page+')').hide();
    $('.pagination .post#page'+page).show();
}
```

If you want next and previous buttons you can easily do so like this:

```
function prevPage() {
    if (page == 1) {
        page = $('.pagination .post').length;
    } else {
        page--;
    }
    showPage(page);
}

function nextPage() {
    if (page == $('.pagination .post').length) {
        page = 1;
    } else {
        page++;
    }
    showPage(page);
}
```

Just note that you need to store the number of the page (I used `page` in the example) if you want to have next and previous buttons.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nv1y59Lu/1/)

Comment: Hi xsquared, Thanks for your answer. It is working :-) However, I also want that the user can click on page number buttons like 1 2 3 4 in additon to the next and previous buttons. How can i do that?

Comment: You can do this even easier than next and previous buttons. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nv1y59Lu/2/). A link that will open a specific page will look like this: `<a href="#" onclick="showPage(1); return false;"></a>`